# Deloying Django app Apach2: 403 Forbidden error. Permission denied: mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-403

I am trying to deploy my Django app with my Digital Ocean droplet. There was a very useful YouTube tutorial that I followed; when he adjusted settings in Apache2, and then refreshes, he sees his Django app, whereas when I do the same, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at 159.223.6.157 Port 80
```

Here you see the setup of my /etc/apache2/sites-available/hbm_project.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/hbm/hbm_project/static
    <Directory /home/hbm/hbm_project/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/hbm/hbm_project/hbm_project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/hbm/hbm_project/hbm_project/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess hbm_app python-home=/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv python-path=/home/hbm/hbm_project python-ho>
    WSGIProcessGroup hbm_app
```

When I look in the error log of Apache2, I see the following error:

```
    [Thu Oct 21 07:07:57.606866 2021] [wsgi:warn] [pid 35891:tid 139970948001088] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=35891): Unable to stat Python home /home/hbm/hbm_project/venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv/lib/python39.zip',
    '/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv/lib/python3.9',
    '/home/hbm/hbm_project/venv/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f4d86a26d40 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

There are some comparable errors on the internet, but none of the things that work for other people seems to work for me.
Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `chown $USER:$USER /home/hbm/hbm_project`

Comment: Hi @balumn, thanks for your reply. I get the following: hbm@hbm-server:~$ sudo chown -r hbm:hbm /home/hbm/hbm_project/
chown: invalid option -- 'r'
Try 'chown --help' for more information.

Comment: @PatrickPel the `-r` was removed from the answer, maybe try now?